# Core Data: Is there a benefit to using a placeholder VC while the persistent container loads, or can you ignore the callback unless there's an error?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm going through the objc.io Core Data book, and they use the following code to set up their persistent container:

```
func createContainer(completion: @escaping (NSPersistentContainer) -> ()) {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
        guard error == nil else { fatalError("Unable to load persistent store: \(error!)") }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(container) }
    }
}
```

(From Chapter 1 available as a sample [here](https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/preview/#setting-up-the-stack))

They add a blank placeholder view controller as the initial view controller, and swap it out with the root view controller after the container loads using the following code in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) -> Bool {
   createContainer { container in
        self.persistentContainer = container
        let storyboard = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootVC") as? RootVC
            else { fatalError("Cannot instantiate root view controller") }
        vc.managedObjectContext = container.viewContext
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    }
    return true
}
```

What's the benefit of doing this as opposed to the way apple suggests in their [Core Data documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack#2882415):

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {        
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()
```

I prefer Apple's way, since it doesn't require creating a placeholder view controller just to swap the placeholder VC out with the app's root VC. Is objc.io's way outdated? Is there a benefit to waiting for the callback to complete vs using a lazy var that returns the container without waiting for the callback?

Comment: I would agree with you, as long as you handle potential cases where the persistentStore is loading or fails to load. think about empty states or refresh/reload buttons

Comment: @erdos Thanks! I was mainly looking for validation. It seems like such a big workaround that I assumed there must be some benefit I was missing.